# Detect Change in Dropdown using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns created in Jquery. The options in the first dropdown are populated in a function when a certain event occurs.

Then based on the selection in the first dropdown, the second dropdown should be populated using a second function, which basically detects a change in the first dropdown. However, the second function doesnot detect any change and I cannot find out why. I am providing both the functions -

Here is the first function -

```
$(document).on("click", ":submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var y = $(this).attr('id');

    if(y.substring(0,6)==='CTopic'){
        var x = $(this).attr('id').substring(6);
        $('#CTopic'+x).hide();
        $('#AnsTopic'+x).append('<option value="All">All</option');
        $('#AnsTopic'+x).append('<option value="Kinematics">Kinematics</option>');
        $('#AnsTopic'+x).append('<option value="Mechanics">Mechanics</option>');
        $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="All">All</option');
        $('#AnsTopic'+x).show();
        $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).show();
    }
});
```

And here is the second function -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("[id^='AnsTopic']").change(function() {
        var x = $(this).attr('id').substring(8);

        $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).html('');
        switch($(this).val()) {
            case 'All':
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="All">All</option>');
            break;
            case 'Kinematics':
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="All">All</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Vectors">Vectors</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Motion">Motion</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Projectile">Projectile</option>');
            break;
            case 'Mechanics':
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="All">All</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Newton Law">Newton Law</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Friction">Friction</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Circular Motion">Circular Motion</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Work-Energy">Work-Energy</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Momentum-Collision">Momentum-Collision</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Rotational Dynamics">Rotational Dynamics</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Gravitation">Gravitation</option>');
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Just to clarify AnsTopic is the first list and AnsSubTopic is the second list. Any suggestion why the change is not being detected

Answer (score 1):

Try to add prevent default action and put change function on body element

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("change", "[id^='AnsTopic']", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
var x = $(this).attr('id').substring(8);

        $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).html('');
        switch($(this).val()) {
            case 'All':
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="All">All</option>');
            break;
            case 'Kinematics':
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="All">All</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Vectors">Vectors</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Motion">Motion</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Projectile">Projectile</option>');
            break;
            case 'Mechanics':
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="All">All</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Newton Law">Newton Law</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Friction">Friction</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Circular Motion">Circular Motion</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Work-Energy">Work-Energy</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Momentum-Collision">Momentum-Collision</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Rotational Dynamics">Rotational Dynamics</option>');
                $('#AnsSubTopic'+x).append('<option value="Gravitation">Gravitation</option>');
            break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Cream. It works. The body element is what gets it working